# Text view not changing value according to the variable in android

Tags: android, textview

My textview should change the value according to the variable predict, but it remains at zero and does not change the value. Is there any solution to it?

Part of my code is: (textView1 is my id of TextView in xml)

```
 public class face extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {
    public int predict;
 public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
predict = model.predict(resizer);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

      txt.setText(Integer.toString(predict)); 
}
}
```

Comment: use like:  `txt.setText(String.Valueof(predict));` for integer values set in textview

Comment: Is predict changing?Could you please log it.Is there any Exception? .For integer values just number+"" will works

Comment: Yes, predict is changing. I saw it during Debugging. Its value was -1 but it showed "0" in my textview

Comment: when do you call onCameraFrame()?It should be called  txt.setText(Integer.toString(predict));

Comment: Try to use txt.setText(""+predict); and see if it helps.

Comment: you should let people know of your status on the question, Sir?

Answer (score 1):

> > My textview should change the value according to the variable predict.but it remains at zero and does not change the value

I am guessing from this that you change the int variable(predict) alot, so whenever you change the variable then you call your `TextView.setText(yourString);`.. `Oncreate` runs only when your activity is initiating or being created.

Comment: But whenever I am setting text outside oncreate it is giving error. What could be the reason of it?

Comment: does onCreate starts before oncameraFrame? does the NPE point to your activity or TextView? can you post the error for me, i can give you a workaround though, give me like an hour, I'm on phone @user1259768

Answer (score 1):

While the variable changes dynamically, the text view should be set dynamically. So, move that from `onCreate()`, which will be calling only once when Activity creates.

```
public class face extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {
    public int predict = 0;
    TextView txt;
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    // confirm that model and resizer are as expected and not null.
    predict = model.predict(resizer);
    if (txt != null)
       txt.setText(""+predict);
    //returns an object of Mat
    }

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     // hope you called setContentView(yourLayout);
     txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     if (txt != null)
      txt.setText(""+predict); 
}
}
```

Comment: But whenever I am setting text outside oncreate it is giving error. What could be the reason of it?

Comment: What error it gives? An exception or incorrect value?

Comment: Yes it is there in my onCreate()

Comment: Then the problem is with your function `onCameraFrame()`.

Answer (score 1):

onCameraFrame is not running on the UI thread so it cannot change views created on the UI thread (such as your textview). Simply put something like this inside onCameraFrame:

```
if (condition) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        txt.setText("whatever");
                    }
                });
            }
```

Note that TextView txt = findTextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); must be done outside onCameraFrame

Answer (score 0):

You should update the text of the TextView every time predict is changing.

```
private void updateTextView() {
      txt.setText(Integer.toString(predict));
}
```

Call this method after assigning a new value to predict:

```
 public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) 
 {     
  predict = model.predict(resizer);
  updateTextView();
 }
```